# Split and concat function in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I am working on data containing something like the following row:

```
Address
--------
AB.CB.2k.SSS.45a
XY.ZZ.3m.WWW.67n
FD.KL.7b.TTT.82l
```

How do I write a SQL query, just to obtain the first 3 parts in each row.

For example: `AB.CB.2k.SSS.45a` should be `AB.CB.2k`

Comment: please provide some code you already tried

Comment: Do the first 3 parts always contain 2 characters before a "." ?

Comment: It differs, not necessarily two characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query get the same

```
select substr(adress,1,instr(address,'.',1,3)-1) from table
```

Comment: If the input is `AB.CD.EF` then this will output `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine string functions `substr` and `instr` to find out 3rd occurrence of `.` and take the substring part required.

```
select substr(Address, 0, instr(Address, '.', 1, 3) - 1)
from your_table;
```

Comment: If the input is `AB.CD.EF` then this will output `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fce97/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses ( Address ) AS
  SELECT 'AB.CB.2k.SSS.45a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'XY.ZZ.3m.WWW.67n' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FD.KL.7b.TTT.82l' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PQ.RS.TU' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MN.OP' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If you want a `NULL` value when there are less than 3 `.` characters in the address then you can use:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
         address,
         1,
         INSTR( address, '.', 1, 3 ) - 1
       ) AS address_part
FROM   addresses
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fce97/1/0)**:

```
| ADDRESS_PART |
|--------------|
|     AB.CB.2k |
|     XY.ZZ.3m |
|     FD.KL.7b |
|       (null) |
|       (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

If you want to return the full string when there are less than 3 `.` characters then:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
         address,
         1,
         CASE pos WHEN 0 THEN LENGTH( address ) ELSE pos - 1 END
       ) AS address_part
FROM   (
  SELECT address,
         INSTR( address, '.', 1, 3 ) AS pos
  FROM   addresses
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fce97/1/1)**:

```
| ADDRESS_PART |
|--------------|
|     AB.CB.2k |
|     XY.ZZ.3m |
|     FD.KL.7b |
|     PQ.RS.TU |
|        MN.OP |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUBSTR("Address",1,INSTR("Address",'.',1,3)-1),"Address") AS "Address"
FROM Table1 t
```

**Output**

```
Address
AB.CB.2k
XY.ZZ.3m
FD.KL.7b
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e05f/2

**EXPLANATION**

**INSTR function**

> The Oracle/PLSQL INSTR function returns the location of a substring in a string.

**Syntax**

```
INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [, th_appearance ] ] )
```

**SUBSTR function**

> SUBSTR function is used to pull substring from a large string.

**Syntax:**

```
SUBSTR(String, Start pos, End pos)
```

**COALESCE Function**

> COALESCE function returns the first non-null expression in the list.
>   If all expressions evaluate to null, then the COALESCE function will
>   return null.

**Syntax**

```
COALESCE( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n )
```

Comment: If the input is `AB.CD.EF` then this will output `NULL`.

Comment: Edited My Answer

Answer (score 1):

Just to join in:

```
substr(address,1, instr(address||'.', '.', 1, 3) -1 )
```

or

```
rtrim(regexp_substr(address||'.','([^.]+[.]){3}'),'.')
```